# Why is there silver foil on a replacement appliance cord?

Tags: electrical, appliances, replacement, cord-and-plug

I bought a [3-prong appliance plug.](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-9-ft-14-3-Medium-Duty-Tool-Replacement-Cord-Black-HD-342-576/303679849) The cord looks like this:

[image]

What is the silver foil? Should it be removed before use?

Comment: Looks like unicorn blood, but maybe it's just tinning.

Comment: Is it foil or more like solder(melted on)?   The picture makes the bare wire look long, most screws/wire attachments only need about 1/2 inch of bare wire.  Too much bare wire can cause problems/shorts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not foil; it's solder. The wires have been *tinned* to keep the stranded wire from fraying when attaching with a wire nut. It's there intentionally, leave it.

Comment: Tinning making the wire makes soldering on a connector easier, since you'd want to run the wire anyway in that case. It may be suboptimal for crimp connections or wire nuts, depending on who you ask. But as others have noted, for either solder or crimp attached lugs, the first thing I would do is cut the exposed conductor shorter, which might mean the  tinning as shipped winds up in the trash. Maybe they just intended it as a temporary measure to keep the stranded wire from fraying before it reaches you.